# Images loaded in simulator but not on device?

Tags: ios, image, extjs, touch, device

I developed an application with Sencha Touch, which runs fine in iOS Simulator. The background image of my document body is shown.

When deploying the app to my iPhone, the background image is not shown anymore. I know, there are problems with case-sensitivity, which differs from simulator to device. I checked my filenames and everything is in lower case.

Here is my CSS code (in ./css/app.css):

```
.x-main {
  background-image: url('../images/swoosh.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

The `swoosh.jpg` exists in the image folder, which is beside `css` folder.

What do I wrong? It's just not working on device, in iOS Simulator, everything is fine.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Found the problem for myself: I have to specify the path as
`url('/public/images/swoosh.jpg')`

Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are using the exact same name means case sensitivity. Simulator is case insensitive while Device is case sensitive. MyImage.jpg and myimage.jpg are two different image in device.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

In my case the problem was calling server files thru http://

I fixed all the problems by changing all links to https://